# SPARQL - extract subset of graph with filter conditions

Tags: sparql, rdf, skos

I am trying to extract a subset of a graph with a multi-hierarchy.

Example Structure:

```
                                         root
                                   /                     \ 
                               SubWant                   subNotWant
                             /         \                           \
                     childWant        childWant                   gCWant
                        /                 \
                       gCWant       gCNotWant
                      /
                   gGCWant
```

the `subWant` subtree is what I would like to get (assume all {'/','\'} or `broader/narrower` relationships)

My current query is:

```
CONSTRUCT
{
  ?children a skos:Concept ;
    skos:broader ?parent ;
    skos:prefLabel ?childPrefLiteral .
   }  

    WHERE {
    ?children skos:broader+ <http://example.com#subWant> ;
        skos:prefLabel ?childPrefLiteral .

    filter(STRBEFORE(?childPrefLiteral, " ") NOT IN (<criteria to prune by>) )
    ?children skos:broader ?parent ;


    # filter parent to only have transitive broader relation to desired concept

    ?parent skos:broader+ <http://example.com#subWant>
  }
```

This query almost works except that it will not include direct children of the `subWant` node. Any recommendations on how to elegantly accomplish this? Note the reason for the last triple `?parent skos:broader <http://example.com#subWant>` is necessary as nodes have multiple parents (multi-hierarchy) - see `gCWant` node in sample graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
?parent skos:broader+ <http://example.com#subWant>
```

into

```
?parent skos:broader* <http://example.com#subWant>
```

The difference between "*" and "+" is that "*" also matches results where `?parent` is `<http://example.com#subWant>`.

Comment: I was so close! This works as I would like it to - thanks so much!